# How to specify branch throught config.gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

For bundler I can do this

`gem 'exception_notification',:git => "git://github.com/smartinez87/exception_notification.git", :branch => "2-3-stable"`

But how can I specify this in config.gem?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be using `config.gem` if you're using `bundler` unless you have a very good reason. The `config.gem` method has been deprecated in favor of bundler.

Answer (score -1):

I'm doing the same thing with exception_notification - my hackety solution was to just install the gem from the right branch system-wide, or in whatever environment manager you're using ([rvm](http://beginrescueend.com/) or [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv)). It's not a real solution (i.e. not compatible with other versions), but it works.

You could also [convert your rails 2 app to use bundler](http://gembundler.com/rails23.html) or upgrade it to rails 3, both of which I've successfully done before with some effort. But... both of those are a lot of work for little gain if you're just trying to maintain legacy code.